# (messageTooBig) how to delete messages on server gcm ?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

my application work with GCM, all success to send and receive messages, but one time I get an error

```
{"multicast_id":9067671989076188106,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MessageTooBig"}]}
```

from the doc that I read said that the payload exceeds the maximum limit, my question.

1 how do we know the payload reaches the maximum limit?

2 how to solve the problems? do I have to delete messages on the server first? or is there another way?

*I am using php as a server to set the GCM

need help, thanks

Comment: from doc: `It has a payload limit of 4096 bytes.` so if your gcm message is bigger then 4KB then you are getting this message ...

Answer (score 0):

Taken from GCM documentation:

```
Messages with payload

Unlike a send-to-sync message, every "message with payload" (non-collapsible message) is 
delivered. The payload the message contains can be up to 4kb.
```

So you have to make sure that your message payload is not larger than 4096 characters.

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#payload) out

Comment: yes, my problem when the message is sent continuously to one device and the device never active for 3 weeks and I get the errorr above, last message I send no more than 4kb, so I think I have to remove on the server first,after it I send again..how i remove all message on gcm server?